# Could not find module `simple-auth-devise/configuration`

Tags: ember.js, devise, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I've just been trying to install `ember-cli-simple-auth`and `ember-cli-simple-auth-devise`.

I went through the exact same process last week and it worked fine. However, since then, Ember CLI has been updated and the install:addon command has been deprecated.

So instead of:

```
ember install:addon ember-cli-simple-auth
ember install:addon ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
```

I am using:

```
ember install ember-cli-simple-auth
ember install ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
```

However, at the end of each of these commands I get:

> The `ember generate` command requires an entity name to be specified.
>   For more details, use `ember help`.

I tried running these commands manually, based upon the "old instructions" found [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth-devise)

```
ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth
ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
```

but then when I start the server I get the following error:

> loader.js:110 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `simple-auth-devise/configuration` imported from `bazmics/initializers/simple-auth-devise`

and the app refuses to load.

The only way I'm able to get the app working again is to remove:

```
"ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
"ember-cli-simple-auth-devise": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
```

from my packages.json, run `npm install` and then restart my server.

Just for good measure, I tried using `npm install...` rather than `ember install...` and then running the installers. No errors, but the same end result.

My versions:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember  : 1.11.1
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: jQuery : 1.11.2
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: -------------------------------
VM11004:66 Ember Inspector Active
```

**Update: 8/4/2015**

I've just tried running the following:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-simple-auth
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
generate ember-cli-simple-auth
generate ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
```

I don't get any errors, but the same thing is happening when I run `ember server` (nothing past the page body renders).

After the above commands the contents of my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "enerlytics",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for enerlytics goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-sass": "^0.6.4",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-sass": "^0.2.11",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.8",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.4",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.10",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-devise": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

The contents of my node_modules folder is:

```
broccoli-asset-rev
broccoli-sass
ember-cli
ember-cli-app-version
ember-cli-babel
ember-cli-bootstrap-sass
ember-cli-content-security-policy
ember-cli-dependency-checker
ember-cli-htmlbars
ember-cli-ic-ajax
ember-cli-inject-live-reload
ember-cli-qunit
ember-cli-simple-auth
ember-cli-simple-auth-devise
ember-cli-uglify
ember-data
ember-export-application-global
```

The contents of my bower.json is:

```
{
  "name": "enerlytics",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.11.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.4",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.8.0-beta.1"
  }
}
```

and the contents of my bower_components folder is:

```
bootstrap-sass-official
ember
ember-cli-shims
ember-cli-test-loader
ember-data
ember-load-initializers
ember-qunit
ember-qunit-notifications
ember-resolver
ember-simple-auth
jquery
loader.js
qunit
qunit-notifications
```

Comment: Do you see "ember-cli-simple-auth" and "ember-cli-simple-auth-devise" directories in your `bower_components` directory?

Comment: This seems to be caused by a recent change to the way Addon generators are handled (see https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3831). I will release a fixed version tomorrow. For now you can just add the dependencies to `package.json` and `bower.json` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing (*"The ember generate command requires an entity name to be specified. For more details, use ember help.
"*) is actually irrelevant as it doesn't prevent the actually important tasks from running and [will be fixed in the next version of Ember CLI probably](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3846/files).

For now you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Hi marcoow, thanks for the tip. If this is the case, I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the rest of the page isn't rendering once I add the dependencies :( I've updated the question with some more info. Thanks again.

Comment: This did indeed resolve my issue in the end. I removed my node_modules and bower_components folders and re-ran npm install and bower install. I then ran the 'ember install ember-cli-simple-auth' and 'ember install ember-cli-simple-auth-devise' commands - ignoring the error as you suggested - and it seems to have worked. Thanks!